# Single function to work on two types of linked lists

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

I have two linked lists :-

```
struct Struct_A_s {
int a;
struct  Struct_A_s *next;
}Struct_A;

struct Struct_B_s {
int a;
int b;
int c;
int d;
struct  Struct_B_s *next;
}Struct_B;
```

I already have several functions which operate on Struct_A.
Things like :

"Add_tail (Struct_A *)", "Remove_tail(Struct_B *)","Add_node(Struct_A *,int pos),Add_head,  etc. etc are in place.

The requirement for me is that I should modify the existing functions so that they can operate on both Struct_A and Struct_B.

In C, is there a way to pass void pointer (or something similar) and write some generic code to work on both Struct_A and Struct_B.
The code size is a big concern here. Currently the only option I see is to rewrite all the code (the linked list operations) from scratch for Struct_B.

Comment: It'll be `struct` not `Struct`.And you are missing a `;` after the last `Struct_B`.Better compile the code before posting on SO.

Comment: corrected based on your comments

Comment: @Rüppell'sVulture Both the structures are listed above ?
I'm sure my question does not depend on the structure type.

Comment: Is the goal to have a single list contain both `Struct_A` elements and `Struct_B` elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `void *` where you'd otherwise use either `Struct_A *` or `Struct_B *`.  You will need to design your APIs carefully.  Typically, you'll end up working a bit like `bsearch()` and `qsort()` taking one or more function pointers that do the structure-specific operations (comparisons in the case of `bsearch()` and `qsort()`).

Note that traversing your linked lists will be hard because the next pointer is at different offsets in the structure.  You might do better with a fixed generic list structure that contains a next pointer and a `void *` to the actual structure.

```
typedef struct List List;

struct List
{
    List *next;
  //List *prev;   // Doubly-linked lists
    void *data;
};
```

This is the difference between 'intrusive' and 'non-intrusive' list structures.  Your existing design uses intrusive list structures; the structure in the list is modified to include the pointer.  The alternative suggested design is non-intrusive; you can create a list of any structure type without modifying the structure type.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways that you could go about it. And I'm sure others more skilled than I may have others to suggest.

- Option A: pass a void pointer and some sort of indication of the data type then cast it.
- Option B: combine the two pointers into a union and pass that.
- Option C: combine the type and the union into a struct and pass that
- Option D: use a more deferenced alternative to a union

Some example code...

```
enum DataType { TYPE_1, TYPE_2 };

struct Type1 { ... };
struct Type2 { ... };

union Data
{
    void*         addr;
    struct Type1* type1;
    struct Type2* type2;
}

struct Object
{
    DataType type;
    union Data data;
}

struct Thing
{
    DataType type;
    void* data;
}

void someFunc1( void* data, DataType type )
{
   switch( type )
   {
       case TYPE_1:
       {
           struct Type1* type1 = (struct Type1*)data;
           ...
           break;
       }
       case TYPE_2:
       {
           struct Type2* type2 = (struct Type2*)data;
           ...
           break;
       }
   }
}

void someFunc2( union Data* data, DataType type )
{
   switch( type )
   {
       case TYPE_1:
       {
           struct Type1* type1 = data->type1;
           ...
           break;
       }
       case TYPE_2:
       {
           struct Type2* type2 = data->type2;
           ...
           break;
       }
   }
}

void someFunc3( struct Object* object )
{
   switch( object->type )
   {
       case TYPE_1:
       {
           struct Type1* type1 = object->data.type1;
           ...
           break;
       }
       case TYPE_2:
       {
           struct Type2* type2 = object->data.type2;
           ...
           break;
       }
   }
}


void someFunc4( struct Thing* thing )
{
   switch( thing->type )
   {
       case TYPE_1:
       {
           struct Type1* type1 = (struct Type1*)thing->data;
           ...
           break;
       }
       case TYPE_2:
       {
           struct Type2* type2 = (struct Type2*)thing->data;
           ...
           break;
       }
   }
}
```

Looking at this another way... if you have a method that only takes `a` then you can do something like this...

```
void myFunc( int a ) { ... };

void someFunc3( struct Object* object )
{
    myFunc( object->type == TYPE_1 ? object->data.type1->a : object->data.type2->a );
}
```

Yet better still... modify the function to accept the object and only differentiate at the bottom...

```
void myFunc( struct Object* object )
{
   int* a;

   switch( object->type )
   {
       case TYPE_1:
       {
           a = &object->data.type1->a
           break;
       }
       case TYPE_2:
       {
           a = &object->data.type2->a;
           break;
       }
       default:
       {
           abort();
       }
   }

   // do work with a as though it were passed in as a pointer to int

   if( object->type == TYPE_2 )
   {
      // do additional work with the b, c, d elements, etc.
   }
}
```

Comment: @k SCOTT :- Thanks for your inputs, a Union appears to be a good solution, but I think in each of the functions above, (The places where you have "..." within switch, I have to rewrite the code right ? I mean to say, you have two types, type1 and type2 in your functions. This is what i want to typically avoid.

Comment: Not necessarily. You only need unique code where you have unique behavior. At some point, you have to differentiate, but until then, you can use the broader notion of the generic data type. The switches I show are intended for use only at the level where differentiation is required. at the higher levels, you can just pass around the generic type.

Comment: Be aware that a `union` approach means that whenever you change any of the structures in the union, or add a new structure to the union, you normally need to recompile everything that uses the union type explicitly.

Comment: @ Jonathan Leffler -- That is true. The (void*) approach lets you suspend the type safe nature of the compiler. I would argue that's not usually a good idea.

Comment: Meh... edited one more time to use pointers in the union as opposed to structures... just to make it more compact and flexible.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler @K Scott
Thanks so much for your answers, It really helped. Actually I had completely forgotten about Unions since I use them so little.I discussed the options you mentioned here, and it turns out using voids to represent the data is actually a very a good option.
I'll just redesign a generic list to make life simpler. Though a phenomenal amount of code changes are now needed but what the heck :-"This is what coders do for a living :-)"
Thanks again SO team for your help.. As always all queries resolved !!

Answer (score 0):

You can redefining the structures as below. You have to do a lot of casting based on the type to modify all your earlier functions to work for both. You need to use Struct_A * for both.

```
struct Struct_A_s {
    int type;
    Struct_A_s *next;
    int a;
}Struct_A;

struct Struct_B_s {
    int type;
    Struct_A *next;
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;
}Struct_B;
```